# animation doesn't work when I show a keyboard

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard, qml

I get a very confused issue in QML project, I set two animations to display/minimize my window:

- after the display animation, I will show a microsoft visual keyboard.
- after the minimize animation, I will hide the keyboard.

Here come an issue, if I show the keyboard, it will affect the minimize animation. When I want to start hide animation, the animation will flash and finish quickly. If I remove the showkeyboard() function, it works well.

The showkeyboard() function is I call some c++ api to show the micorsoft visual keyboard.

here is my some code:

```
PropertyAnimation {
    id: initWindow
    target: root
    from: 0
    to: mat.height
    property: 'height'
    duration: 1000
    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
    onRunningChanged: {
        console.log("root.visibility in initWindow:",root.visibility);
        if(!initWindow.running && root.visibility != Window.Hidden){
            inputKit.showKeyboard()
            console.log("here is initWindow animation.")
        }
    }
}

PropertyAnimation  {
    id: closeWindow
    target: root
    property: "height"
    from: mat.height
    to: 0
    duration: 1000
    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
    onRunningChanged: {
        if(!closeWindow.running){
            inputKit.hidekeyboard();
            root.hide();
            console.log("here is closewindow animation.")
            console.log("root.visibility in closeWindow:",root.visibility);
        }
    }
}
function minimizeWindow(){
    closeWindow.start();
    hiding();
}

function showWindow(){
    root.x = mat.x;
    root.y = mat.y;
    root.width = mat.width;
    root.height = mat.height;
    root.requestActivate();
    root.requestUpdate();
    initWindow.start();
    root.show();
    showing();
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should post minimal *working* example. It's impossible to test you code now.

Comment: If I remvoe inputKit.showKeyboard() and inputKit.hidekeyboard();, it will work.... :(

Comment: How is the keyboard rendered? In software or in hardware?